# How can we change datatype of a field from string to double in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

How can we change datatype of a field from string to double in mongodb. I had tried some code but not working.

At-present I have `28000` entries in table.
I am using mongodb `2.6.10`.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
db.booking.find({prepayment_amount: {$exists: true}}).forEach(function(obj) {
     obj.prepayment_amount = new parseDouble(obj.prepayment_amount);
     db.booking.save(obj);
    });
```

**Error**

When I run this code in mongo shell I am getting

```
> db.booking.find({prepayment_amount: {$exists: true}}).forEach(function(obj) {
...      obj.prepayment_amount = new parseDouble(obj.prepayment_amount);
...      db.booking.save(obj);
...     });
2017-08-04T09:28:04.670+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: parseDouble is not defined :
@(shell):2:6
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:501:1
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: define "not working" please. Is it throwing errors? What do the "strings" you are trying to convert actually look like? I also note that I know I've already given you an answer with a much more efficient loop than what you are using here.

Comment: Taking a look at a previous question of yours it would seem that the data is actually stored something like `prepayment_amount: "55"` So if you only problem here is that you are "expecting" it to show as `prepayment_amount: 55.00` then that may well be simply all about the interface you are viewing the data from. If the data is actually stored as a "double" then it will match BSON Type 1. So using [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) `.find({ "prepayment_amount": { "$type": 1 } }).count()` should return equal to the collection count after conversion.

Comment: Or more to the point, if the job is in fact done then `.find({ "prepayment_amount": { "$type": 2 } }).count()` which is looking for "string" should return `0`. Meaning the conversion was correctly done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added error response also in my question

Comment: Missed that completely. Because it's `parseFloat` and not `parseDouble` since there is no such method. Or of course simply `parseInt` if there is no decimal point in any of the strings. Also you do not use `new`.

Comment: Also there is `Number(obj.prepayment_amount)` as a built in function for the shell aside from the other built in JavaScript methods. More modern mongodb releases have `NumberDecimal()` as well, but not 2.6

Comment: @Neil Lunn, Please check and correct me `var ops = [];
db.booking.find({prepayment_amount: {$exists: true}}).forEach(doc => {
            doc.prepayment_amount = parseFloat(doc.prepayment_amount);

            ops.push({
    "updateOne": {
                "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
      "update": {
                    "$set": { "prepayment_amount": doc.prepayment_amount }
      }
    }
  });

  if ( ops.length >= 500 ) {
      db.booking.bulkWrite(ops);
      ops = [];
  }
});

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
    db.booking.bulkWrite(ops);
    ops = [];
}`